# How can i know the balance of the account where the contract is deployed from a method?

Tags: nearprotocol

I´m trying to write a function that returns the balance of the account where the contract is deployed.

Something with the following form:

```
pub fn get_balance(&self) -> Balance {
       
        env::account_balance()
    }
```

The above code returns the balance of the account that is calling the method, the signer. Is there a way to make it returns the balance of the contract account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. near_sdk:env::account_balance() already do what i was looking for. It retrieves the balance of the contract account.

I was lacking a way to check it properly. To do it, i used near state [account_name] on the cli to verify if the balance returned was the master or subaccount (where the contract was deployed) balance.

So the answer would be:

```
pub fn get_balance(&self) -> Balance {
       
        env::account_balance()
    }
```

noting that to have the transferible balance, it would have to take into account the min balance used for storage.

Comment: Thanks for following up with your answer!